# How to retrieve the DS-160 application number after closing the browser window?

Tags: visas, usa, applications

Due to time out, my application exited without completion. I failed in retrieving the application because my surname is only 4 letters.  Since I already made the payment with the ID no. of the previous application, if I fill in another new form, will there be any impact on the payment?

Comment: You retrieve a DS-160 application with the application id, which is sent to your email I believe. Where are you filling the DS-160 application ? When you make a payment you get a confirmation email, check your inbox. Payment is for the original application, you cannot change it now.

Answer (score 9):

If you closed the browser and forgot to save the Application ID number and you have finish it, is close to impossible to recover but I was able to do it as follows.
The Website doesn't allow anymore to click on forgot application ID, this is what I did, I was using Chrome, for other browser find out yourself based on this steps:
1-Enable browsing offline (not necessary, maybe useful in the future)
go to chrome://flags/#show-saved-copy select enable secondary
2-Go to browse cache
open a tab chrome://cache/
I was able to find it in this URL
https://ceac.state.gov/GenNIV/General/complete/complete_uscontact.aspx?node=USContact
but it can be in other URL as well. search in the text for the word lblRecoveryAppID it will be located right after
right here

Comment: For firefox, the entry is "RecoveryAppID" or "Application ID". I never could imagine I have to grep into firefox cache for this purpose.

Comment: This does not work anymore as chrome://cache/ is not supported anymore

Answer (score 7):

On mac look for google chrome cache location-
Sample:

```
/Users/{user}/Library/Caches/Google/Chrome/Default/Cache
```

Then grep -> `grep lblRecoveryAppID *`
It will list all cached application ids

Comment: Perfect! It would take a minute to finish searching.

Comment: Once I got the file names from the grep command, I had to search for lblAppID  to find the application ID.

Comment: In windows you can goto C:\{user}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache and do a -> findstr lblRecoveryAppID *

Comment: In my case I needed: `grep -Ra lblRecoveryAppID .` to account for binary files and avoid "too many arguments" error.

Answer (score 4):

The Consular Electronic Application Center gives [instructions on how to retrieve a DS-160](https://ceac.state.gov/GENNIV/Help/Content/Retrieve%20an%20Application%20ID.htm) application, either by using the Application ID or, if you 'forgot your application id,' to do so by answering your security questions.

**Update** Since the above no longer work below are few ways you could retrieve the application id from the chrome cache.
Note: I tried only on Mac, will update if I could find something similar to windows.

Open Terminal and

```
cd /Users/<user>/Library/Caches/Google/Chrome/Profile 2/Cache
grep -Ri "APPLICATION ID" .
vim <the first file>
Search for "Application ID" using /Application ID
```

You should be able to retrieve the Id from the cache.

Comment: This does not work anymore

Comment: It worked for me.