# Retrieve the DS-160 application ID?

Tags: visas, usa, paperwork, applications, h1b-visas

Good Morning, I filled the DS-160 (not submitted) and I saved my application id in a system but my system / OS is crashed.
What is the way to retrieve the DS-160 application id.

I followed the steps provided in it and not able to find the DS-160 - Forgot your link, could some one help me on this please
[How to retrieve a US DS-160 confirmation page?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/118590/how-to-retrieve-a-us-ds-160-confirmation-page)

Or the only way is to create the new DS-160?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve the DS-160 application number after closing the browser window?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/95081/how-to-retrieve-the-ds-160-application-number-after-closing-the-browser-window)

Comment: @RedBaron my system is crashed, It is not the same case, please remove the flag

Comment: Ok...although it may be possible to retrieve the cache info by plugging the hard drive (if functional) into another system.

Comment: Best option is almost certainly just to start again.  There's no issues creating multiple DS-160s - the old one will not be used and will eventually be deleted.